# How do I convert only a portion of an MP3 file to WAV at a certain frequency, from the command-line?

Tags: sound, software-recommendation, command-line, mp3

This transcodes the entire .mp3 to a .wav

```
mpg123 -w output.wav input.mp3
```

Is there any way I can transcode a portion from the 10 second mark to the 20 second mark at a 44100hz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Note* : What you want isn't directly possible with `mpg123`. I recommend using [SoX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SoX) instead -- the [*"Swiss Army Knife of sound processing"*](http://sox.sourceforge.net/).

#### Transcoding only a portion of an MP3 file to WAV *and* resampling it to a different rate

- Install SoX along with MP3 format support from the terminal with `sudo apt-get install sox libfmt-sox-mp3`
- You can then perform the transcoding you require via this command:

  ```
  sox -V3 input.mp3 -r 44100 output.wav trim 0:10 0:10
  ```

  - The `-r` option, inserted before the output file name, indicates that you want to resample the output to 44100 Hz.
  - The `trim` option, inserted *after* the output file name, indicates that you want to transcode only the portion beginning at *0 minutes and 10 seconds* (first `0:10`), for a length of *10 seconds* from that point (second `0:10`).
  - The `-V3` is optional and simply tells `sox` to display the input/output parameters and transcoding progress for your information.