# How to download and install ffmpeg from Launchpad?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, ffmpeg, launchpad, source-packages

I'm trying to understand how to install the `ffmpeg` package from  [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg).

The [ffmpeg website](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-linux) links to that page when you try to download it for Linux.

Comment: Actually I can't find that exact Launchpad link anywhere on that page. What you appear to be looknig for is on [this page](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#get-sources)

Comment: You haven't said what you want to do with ffmpeg, but the published binaries can be a little restrictive due to the different licences used in some libraries. You may want to compile ffmpeg to get the functions that you need -- [this is a useful guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) of how to compile ffmpeg with various options.

Comment: Please add what release of Ubuntu you are using, i.e., Trusty (14.04), Xenial (16.04),  Yakkety (16.10)

Comment: @doug Sorry, I am using Kubuntu 16.04 and I want to download it for Paraview.

The reason I want to download it from launchpad is because the Launchpad

Comment: @ElderGeek The third link on that page "Ubuntu - Official packages for Vivid, Wily, Xenial" links to the webpage I gave.

Comment: As of this moment the most current ffmpeg source code for 16.04 (xenial) is available [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/7:2.8.10-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`ffmpeg`** is available in the official Ubuntu repositories :
- **[xenial](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ffmpe) | [xenial-updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/ffmpeg) | [yakkety](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/ffmpeg) | [yakkety-updates](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety-updates/ffmpeg)** -

```
apt policy ffmpeg
ffmpeg:
  Installed: 7:3.0.5-0ubuntu0.16.10.1
  Candidate: 7:3.0.5-0ubuntu0.16.10.1
  Version table:
 *** 7:3.0.5-0ubuntu0.16.10.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety-security/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7:3.0.2-1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu yakkety/universe amd64 Packages
```

To install it open a terminal and execute this command :

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

There is no need to download `ffmpeg` from launchpad.

**Update addressing your comment about missing packages after an installation using `apt`**

When you install `ffmpeg` using `apt`, the 'additional packages' are getting installed alongside automatically, maybe something went wrong in your case. For example - here my initial setup - these packages were installed after I had executed the command `sudo apt install ffmpeg` :

```
ffmpeg (7:3.0.2-1ubuntu3)
i965-va-driver (1.7.1-1)
libaacs0 (0.8.1-1)
libass5 (0.13.2-1)
libavcodec57 (7:3.0.2-1ubuntu3)
libavdevice57 (7:3.0.2-1ubuntu3)
libavfilter6 (7:3.0.2-1ubuntu3)
libavformat57 (7:3.0.2-1ubuntu3)
libavresample3 (7:3.0.2-1ubuntu3)
libavutil55 (7:3.0.2-1ubuntu3)
libbdplus0 (0.1.2-1)
libbluray1 (1:0.9.3-2)
libbs2b0 (3.1.0+dfsg-2.2)
libchromaprint0 (1.3-1build1)
libcrystalhd3 (1:0.0~git20110715.fdd2f19-11build1)
libdc1394-22 (2.2.4-1)
libflite1 (2.0.0-release-2)
libgme0 (0.6.0-3)
libgsm1 (1.0.13-4)
libmodplug1 (1:0.8.8.5-2)
libmp3lame0 (3.99.5+repack1-9build1)
libopenal-data (1:1.17.2-1)
libopenal1 (1:1.17.2-1)
libopenjpeg5 (1:1.5.2-3.1)
libpostproc54 (7:3.0.2-1ubuntu3)
librubberband2v5 (1.8.1-6ubuntu2)
libschroedinger-1.0-0 (1.0.11-2.1build1)
libsdl1.2debian (1.2.15+dfsg1-4)
libshine3 (3.1.0-4)
libsoxr0 (0.1.2-1)
libssh-gcrypt-4 (0.7.3-1)
libswresample2 (7:3.0.2-1ubuntu3)
libswscale4 (7:3.0.2-1ubuntu3)
libtwolame0 (0.3.13-1.2)
libva1 (1.7.1-2)
libvdpau1 (1.1.1-3ubuntu1)
libx264-148 (2:0.148.2699+gita5e06b9-1)
libx265-79 (1.9-3)
libxvidcore4 (2:1.3.4-1)
libzvbi-common (0.2.35-11)
libzvbi0 (0.2.35-11)
mesa-va-drivers (12.0.3-1ubuntu2)
mesa-vdpau-drivers (12.0.3-1ubuntu2)
va-driver-all (1.7.1-2)
vdpau-driver-all (1.1.1-3ubuntu1)
```

This is from an Ubuntu 16.10 installation - packages and versions are different in other editions.
Other packages like `libavcodec-extra57`, which provides some additional de/encoders or any dev-versions have to be installed manually.
If you are still running Ubuntu 14.04, you can install `libav-tools` (a fork of `ffmpeg` which temporarily replaced `ffmpeg` in Ubuntu 14.04) instead.

Comment: Actually, I need ffmpeg as a pre-requisite for Paraview. I tried the apt based installation, but it doesn't install number of important other things (libavcodec, libavutils, libavdevice, libavformat, and libswscale).

Comment: The page on Launchpad listed all of those other things as bundled with the package, so I wanted to download it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the update.
I re-did the apt based installation.
To check if the other packages were installed alongside it, I ran the command `sudo find / -name "avcodec.h"` (it should return the location of the header file `avcodec.h` that is supposed to be installed with the package libavcodec), I get nothing. So that confirms that the other packages aren't being installed.

Comment: Do you have any ideas about what might be causing the other packages to not install? I am doing all of this on Kubuntu 16.04, not Ubuntu 16.04....could that be the source of the problem (I know that sounds stuipid, but I really can't think of anything I'm doing differently than you)?

Comment: @user3595843 : You can check whether the libav related packages are installed by running : dpkg --get-selections | grep libav ... alternatively you can do it with : apt policy <package-name> for each package ! :)

Comment: @cl-ntebox So, I `sudo apt-get install`-ed the dev versions of the packages manually (libavcodec-dev, etc), and it got the Paraview installation process much further ahead.
Still haven't been able to figure out what went wrong the first time, though.

Comment: @user3595843 : Well, I also don't have an idea what went wrong before, but most important is that we could achieve what you asked for in your question : getting installed the complete ffmpeg packages ! :)

Comment: Overwrought answer that doesn't directly answer question, dv'ing

Answer (score 4):

You copied the *Ubuntu - packages for Vivid, Wily, Xenial* link from the ffmpeg website incorrectly. The correct link is: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg. At this webpage you can show the ffmpeg .deb packages that are available to be  downloaded by unfolding the white triangles on the left side of the page. The ffmpeg packages at this website were last updated two weeks ago.

In Ubuntu 12.04, 16.04, 16.10, 17.04, 17.10 and 18.04 and later (but not 14.04) you can also install ffmpeg from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

Comment: I opened the white triangle, but it gives separate .deb files for each of the software listed. Is there any way to install all of the listed software in one go? I'm assuming there should be a way to do this, otherwise why would they present all of these software together as one package?

Comment: Some of the packages on the list of .deb software are mutually incompatible, so that if you install one of the packages of the pair of incompatible packages, you will get an error message if you try to install the other one. The simplest way to avoid this type of problem is to install the packages carefully, one package at a time. It takes longer, but it's safer to install the packages that way.

Answer (score 2):

Precompiled binaries of Paraview don't need or use ffmpeg libs so I'll assume that you are looking to build Paraview with ffmpeg support.

In that case this should do it, it will install all 9 -dev packages. Likely that you don't need them all, if desired remove the last package to get a shortlist of  4 -dev packages.

`sudo apt install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavdevice-dev`

It doesn't hurt to have a couple of extra -dev's installed & many sources will only use what they need/support.

Answer (score 1):

### To download a program off of launchpad

First look for the packaged `deb` file for your version of Ubuntu *(a `deb` for Debian/Mint etc may work for Ubuntu - RPMs are for fedora/centos/redhat/suse, other packaging formats are available for different distros)*. This can a annoying to find on launchpad (the link may just be out of date) - but is still possible to something usable (***NOTE**: Read the last part of the answer before trying for ffmpeg...)*:

1. Go to [Code](https://code.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg) at the top
2. Get the most relevant branch (e.g. [vidid/ffmpeg](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/ffmpeg/vivid) for 15.04)
3. Find a 'recipe' with successful builds ([example](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eedes-neves7/+recipe/ffmpeg-daily)) then download the deb files for that ([example](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eedes-neves7/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/7110924)) - get `amd64` if possible for [64bit](https://askubuntu.com/a/41334/1785960), else use the `i*86` packages (for 32bit).

If you can't find that, you can usually get a source code download (e.g. for 14.04, [here](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/ffmpeg/trusty/revision/55?start_revid=55) - the ffmpeg site version is https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html). You then should be able to compile and install that - instructions are available [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file), and usually in a `README` file in the stuff you download. Please note that if you do not use `checkinstall` etc, you may need to remove the package with `sudo make uninstall` or similar to remove the compile program, hence why it is usually better to use packaged versions

### Too add a PPA

Launchpad can better used with PPAs, instructions for using them can be found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/4987#4987).

---

### FFmpeg Specifically...

The method you use to install `ffmpeg` depends on the version of Ubuntu you are using. For [recent supported versions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) (since 15.04 (vivid), so 16.04 & 16.10 currently), this should work and will get `ffmpeg` from the offical repos ([here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ffmpeg&searchon=names&section=all)):

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

However if you are using 14.04 (and some other versions from around that point), you can use `libav-tools`  a fork of that project

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

This was because `ffmpeg` was removed from the offical ubuntu repositories for a few versions. however ***ffmpeg is still available from third party sources for them*** (such as `ffmpeg` source code, PPAs, and `deb` downloads. This is covered extensively [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432542/is-ffmpeg-missing-from-the-official-repositories-in-14-04).