# How can I install OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) without errors on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, obs-studio

What are the steps to build OBS for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS without dependencies or ffmpeg errors?

I initially followed the Ubuntu official documentation here: https://obsproject.com/wiki/install-instructions#linux as follow:

`$sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
$sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install obs-studio`

It would lead to issue with package versions:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 obs-studio : Depends: libavcodec57 (>= 7:3.4.4) but 7:3.4.2-2 is to be installed or
             libavcodec-extra57 (>= 7:3.4.4) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libavdevice57 (>= 7:3.4.4) but 7:3.4.2-2 is to be installed
              Depends: libavformat57 (>= 7:3.4.4) but 7:3.4.2-2 is to be installed
              Depends: libavutil55 (>= 7:3.4.4) but 7:3.4.2-2 is to be installed
              Depends: libswresample2 (>= 7:3.4.4) but 7:3.4.2-2 is to be installed
              Depends: libswscale4 (>= 7:3.4.4) but 7:3.4.2-2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Building from the source, clone with Git:

`git clone --recursive https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio.git`

...still gives me errors:

`CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find FFmpeg (missing: FFMPEG_AVCODEC_LIBRARIES
  FFMPEG_AVCODEC_INCLUDE_DIRS avcodec avdevice avutil avformat)`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following libraries before running cmake and make:

`$sudo apt install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libavdevice-dev`
(ref: [How to download and install ffmpeg from Launchpad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865511/how-to-download-and-install-ffmpeg-from-launchpad/865835#865835))

Next you will need:
`$sudo apt-get install libmbedtls-dev`

and Qt5Svg is required as well:
`$sudo apt-get install libqt5svg5-dev`